# android with JDBC. createStatement() does not exist?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jdbc

I am trying to create a connection with a database using JDBC on my android project. I am following a tutorial which says to import a jar and then create a connection in the activity. Everything is ok, but in the connection statement i get an error

> Cannot resolve method 'createStatement()'

if I try to get into the reference of the method, it says

> cannot find decleration to go to

This method comes from the jar i have imported? (jtds-1.3.1)
Is there anything else i am missing here?

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        Connection con;
        String usernam = params[0];
        String passwordd = params[1];
        if(usernam.trim().equals("")|| passwordd.trim().equals(""))
            z = "Please enter Username and Password";
        else
        {
            try
            {
                con = connectionclass(un, pass, db, ip);        // Connect to database
                if (con == null)
                {
                    z = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                }
                else
                {
                    // Change below query according to your own database.
                    String query = "select * from owner where mail = '" + usernam.toString() + "' and password = '"+ passwordd.toString() +"'  ";
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        z = "Login successful";
                        isSuccess=true;
                        con.close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        z = "Invalid Credentials!";
                        isSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return z;
    }
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection connectionclass(String user, String password, String database, String server)
{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection = null;
    String ConnectionURL = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + database + ";user=" + user+ ";password=" + password + ";";
        connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
    }
    catch (SQLException se)
    {
        Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
    }
    return connection;
}
```

I got the same problem with the `close()` method
[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: Do you've any own Connection class ?

Comment: yeah, this code i have posted is inside a connection class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you've got to do is specify the class name fully:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product","root","");
```

No need for a cast, and the error you're reporting will now go away, as the compiler will be looking for the method in the right class.

Or just rename your own class `Connection`.

Comment: I remove the casting from the connection and change the method type to java.sql.Connection and the errors go away. Thanks!